# Find match value Excel cell from a row

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

This is an Excel problem.
I have an Excel Rows with the following values:

```
cell value      1, 2, x,  ,1=,2=,  ,x=,2
cell address   a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1
```

I want to get all non-empty cell addresses from the above row.

```
i.e.
a1,b1,c1,e1,f1,h1,i1
```

Is it possible using vba/vbs to do the job?

thank you very much

Comment: "I want to get" -- what does that mean? What is your code so far? Where are you stuck? This site is not a code creating service. Happy to help, but you need to show your own effort. I suggest a loop that inspects the range A1:I1 and writes the results into an array.

Comment: I am using a for-loop to check each cell, the searching speed. is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

To demonstrate, run this, and observe result in the Imediate window

```
Sub demo()
    Dim rng As Range, rNonEmpty As Range
    Set rng = [A1:I1]
    Set rNonEmpty = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    Debug.Print rNonEmpty.Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will check an area of 10 rows by 1000 columns and finally will show the addresses of the non blank cells in cell A20:

```
Sub no_blank_cells()
   Dim wks As Worksheet
   Set wks = ActiveSheet
   m = ""
   maxrows = 10
   maxcolumns = 1000
   For i = 1 To maxrows
       For j = 1 To maxcolumns
           a = Cells(i, j)
           If a <> "" Then
               m = m & Cells(i, j).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & ", "
           End If
       Next j
   Next i
   msg = MsgBox(m, vbInformation)
   wks.Cells(20, 1) = m
End Sub
```

If you want to change the area to be searched, modify the value of the variables `maxrows`and `maxcolumns`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub WriteNonNulValue()
    '/*SELECT SHEET TO ANALIZE*/
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    '/*SELECT ROW TO READ*/
    Row_to_read = 1
    '/*SELECT ROW IN WHICH WRITE*/
    Row_to_write = 2
    '/*NUMBER OF COLUMNS TO ANALIZE*/
    Columns_to_analize = 11
    '/*COUNTER WRITE*/
    Columns_to_write = 1
    For i = 1 To Columns_to_analize
        If Trim(Cells(Row_to_read, i)) <> "" Then
            '/*WRITE ADDRESS NO EMPTY CELLS*/
            Cells(Row_to_write, Columns_to_write) = Cells(Row_to_read,i).Address
            '/*INCREMENT COUNTER WRITE*/
            Columns_to_write = Columns_to_write + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```